# Main user gone after upgrading to MacOS Siera

Tags: macos, mac

I have just upgraded to MacOS Siera, and all of my users are no longer recognized.

I can see my user folder in the Users folder but OS won't recognize it.

I have looked around but only found issues revolving FileVault, which I have not used in the past (though I have tried the suggested solutions and they did not work).

To make it clear - none of my old users are available.

One thing I have noticed is that the OS has technically installed on a different partition than the old OS, which might have something to do with that (I had a small, 256MB partition created to allow the installation process, as instructed on apple site).

How can I restore the users?

Comment: You can't install macOS into a 256MB partition (can you link to the instructions you've used?). Also, are the user folders still shown when you run `ls -l /Users` in Terminal? What do you mean by "I see the folder but [the] OS won't recognize it"? Maybe adding some screenshots will make it easier to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on a different partition, it's basically a different system. You'll need to upgrade the correct partition.